# Why might a return statement in nginx.conf return a plain text file location to the browser instead of the actual file to be rendered?

Tags: nginx

**Environment:** Nginx, Node.js

I'm experimenting with error handling in Nginx and I'm having no luck returning files.

In the simplified `ngxinx.conf` below if the http `request_method` is not `GET`, `HEAD` or `POST` I'd like the server to return the 405.html error page.

**Hoped for output:** 405.html is sent to the browser.

**Actual output:** this plain text is sent to the browser.  `http://www.example.com/html/405.html`

Note: I'm testing this in Postman so I don't have to install an additional extension in Chrome that allows sending various HTTP methods to the server.

**Relevant portions of my config:**

```
server {

    include conf.d/listen-80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
        return 405 $scheme://www.example.com/html/405.html;
    }

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {

    include conf.d/listen-443;

    server_name example.com;

    include conf.d/letsencrypt;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
        return 405 $scheme://www.example.com/html/405.html;
    }

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

}

server {

    include conf.d/listen-443;

    server_name www.example.com;

    include conf.d/letsencrypt;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
        return 405 $scheme://www.example.com/html/405.html;
    }

    root /srv/example/views/public;

    location ~* \.(htm|html)$ {
        include conf.d/content-security-policy-html-rendered;
        include conf.d/cache-control-30-days;
        include conf.d/security-headers-html-rendered;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL after `return nnn` is treated only as a target URL for redirection code (301, 302, 303, 307 and 308 status codes). The documentation doesn't clearly tell what it does when code is something else.

To get an error page in your case, use the following:

```
if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$) {
    return 405;
}

error_page 405 /html/405.html;
```

This will tell nginx to send `/html/405.html` when status code 405 is returned.

Comment: Note that if you want the user agent to actually receive the 405 error status, you need to serve a local file. If you provide a full URL to `error_page` then it will send a redirect to that URL (by default a 302, and you can only set it to 301, 302, 303, 307, and 308).

Comment: See also: [`limit_except GET POST {deny all;}`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except)